# Making Overlays section in OpenLayers LayerSwitcher exclusive

Tags: openlayers-2, layers

At the simplest level I need to figure out how to create a customized OpenLayers `LayerSwitcher` **Overlays** section which is not using Checkboxes, but uses `RadioButton`s instead.

For my application its not desirable for the user to be able to select multiple layers.  Eventually I'm going to need to be able to create group sections in the Overlay section of the `LayerSwitcher`.

I've seen the customized LayerSwitcher example on the OpenLayers site, but I can only get it to work in Chrome.  I need to be able to support Safari on an iPad.

Comment: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/controls.html has both checkbox and radio buttons

Comment: Does this example do what you want? Or are there specific customizations you need on the layer control? http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/google.html Seems to work on Safari on a pc - though not tried it on an iPad.

Comment: The BaseLayers section of the LayerSwitcher are exclusive (use Radio Buttons) by default.  This example does not have any Overlays.  I need to make the Overlays exclusive like the BaseLayers.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For Grouping Layers in Openlayers use **GeoExt Tree**

[image]

Live Example

http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/tree.html

Javascript source for GeoExt
http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/tree.js

Comment: Interesting - I will check this out.  Any ideas on how to make the Overlays exclusive?  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: After reading further about GeoExt, it seems this will not work for me.  GeoExt requires also using ExtJS which requires buying a license, which I won't be able to do.  I need to stick with free open-source software.  Thanks for the reply though.